# How to change rs.getDate to get local date time instead?

Tags: java, jdbc

I was looking for a solution to my problem. I was coding my JdbcImpl file and I got an error when I was coding this :
[rs.getDate create an error in a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGgkd.png)

```
Enchere enchereResultSet = new Enchere(
    //Changer le getDate to LocalDateTime
rs.getDate("date_encheres"),
rs.getInt("montant_enchere"),
rs.getInt("no_article"),
rs.getInt("no_utilisateur"));
```

I found the fix! It seems simple, just go for this instead:

```
Enchere enchereResultSet = new Enchere(
    //Changer le getDate to LocalDateTime
rs.getTimestamp("date_enchere").toLocalDateTime(),
rs.getInt("montant_enchere"),
rs.getInt("no_article"),
rs.getInt("no_utilisateur"));
```

[The solution in a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAjf8.png)

Do I have the right to share the fix if I found it while writing a post here? I share it because  it will maybe help beginner like me in the future.

Comment: You are welcome and encouraged to post and accept an Answer to your own Question. See meta.stackoverflow.com for details.

Comment: Your fix is the wrong one (it works, but it may have unnecessary overhead). You should use `rs.getObject("date_enchere", LocalDateTime.class)`. Note that if you used `getDate` before, and you are actually retrieving date information, then use `LocalDate`: `rs.getObject("date_enchere", LocalDate.class)`